# Linked List and nodes

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I am currently Learning how Linked Lists work in C++ and I have written this code, which gives me compilation errors and I don't get the resalts that I got in an earlier version of the code. This is an early version of my previous code that I lost.

So what I need help with:

How should the add function (that puts an element last in the list) look like?

What do I need to add to the deconstructors?

And the remove_if( T& t )that should delete all elements with the value t, remove_if(predicate& pred) that should delete all the elements pred returns true?

What do I need to add to Between T> ?

My code that I've edited:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    template <class T>
    class List;

    template <class T>
    class Node {
    public:
      Node ( T *t) : data(t), next(0) {}
      ~Node();
    private:
      T *data;
      Node* next;
      friend class List<T>;
    };

    template <class T>

    class Predicate {
     public:
      Predicate() {}
      virtual bool operator()( const T& v) = 0;
    };

    template <class T>
    class List {
    public:
      List() : first(new Node<T>(T())) {} //"dummy"-node

      void add( T *t );
      void remove_if( T t );
      void remove_if( Predicate<T> &pred );
      void print(); 

    private:  
      Node<T> *first;
    };
```

Main:

```
    int main()
    {

      List<int> intlista;
      intlista.add( new int(1) );
      intlista.add( new int(2) );
      intlista.add( new int(3) );
      intlista.add( new int(2) );
      intlista.add( new int(4) );
      intlista.add( new int(5) );
      intlista.add( new int(6) );

      intlista.print();

      intlista.remove_if( 2 );
      intlista.print();

      Between<int> one_to_four(1,4);
      intlista.remove_if( one_to_four );  
      intlista.print();
    }
```

Wrote:

```
    { 1 2 3 2 4 5 6 }
    { 1 3 4 5 6 }
    { 5 6 }
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: You need to show `List::add`'s definition.

Comment: @juanchopanza

"Between wasn't declared in this area"
"expected primary-expression Before "int""
"expected ; Before "int""
"one_to_four wasn't declared in this area"

Comment: @MattPhillips List::add is supposed to put an element last in the list but I've lost the code :/

Comment: @MarketingMark Your `Between` error is due to not having included the declaration of the class `Between`.  This is a pretty basic question actually, you may be getting a little ahead of yourself in your C++ studies (but keep at it by all means!).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't actually answer your question, but:

```
template <class T>
class Node {
public:
  Node ( T *t) : data(t), next(0) {}
  ~Node();
private:
  T *data;
  Node* next;
  friend class List<T>;
};
```

seems wrong to store a pointer to T in the linked list. The whole point of templated linked lists is that the data stored can be stored directly in the list, as is (and if, for whatever good or bad reason, you want to store `int *` in the list, then you make `List<int *> list;`.

Now for your actual question:
Is `Between` one of your classes? If so, have you included the header for it?

Comment: Hi. Between should be a pred so the program can be compiled and be able to run

Comment: Yes - But I need to go at one problem at a time, could I get help of how I should write an add() method and what I should add to the deconstructors?

Comment: Fix anything that stops it from compiling first. Just make an empty `add()` function, and include the right includes. Then have a go at writing a proper add function and post if you have problems - we're not really here to write the code for you (especially as you learn very little from that).